# Is LiteDB known to work with dotnet Core 5.0?

Tags: litedb

I am about to port a Windows forms application (dotnet 4.7x) to dotNet Core 5. The application uses LiteDB (all else is straight c# winforms stuff). Before starting I need to determine if LiteDB 5.10 will work with Core 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

LiteDB `5.x` is .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Standard 2.0 compatible. You can work with LiteDB in any target framework that .NE TStantard 2.0 is compatible, like:

- .NET 5
- .NET Core 2+
- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- Mono 5.4
- Xamarin.iOS 10.14
- Xamarin.Mac 3.8
- Xamarin.Android 8
- UWP 10.0.16299
- Unity 2018.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/net-standard